# Cannot compile Java code - "class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 48.0"

Tags: java

I know that this appears everywhere with a bunch of threads but I followed the instructions and it did not work! 
I get the following error:

> cannot access java.lang.Object
>   bad class file: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
>   class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 48.0
>   Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
>       public static void main (String [] args){
>                                    ^
>   1 error

I downloaded the latest runtime, and the latest JDK. If I do /java version in Terminal (I'm using Mac), I get:

> java version "1.8.0_60"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)XXXXX-MacBook-Pro:~ XXXXX$

What should I do now? I set the JAVA_HOME and it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're using an old jdk for compilation. How are you compiling? What does `javac -version` say?

Comment: javac: invalid flag: -version
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                        Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                   Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}    Generate only some debugging info
  -O                        Optimize; may hinder debugging or enlarge class file
  -nowarn                   Generate no warnings
  -verbose                  Output messages about what the compiler is doing
Etc.

Comment: The odd thing is, on Dr Java it works, while on CodeRunner it doesn't. I looked into the settings on CodeRunner, what does this mean:eval $compiler ??

Comment: Public support for v1.4 ended in Oct 2008.  What code are you running that is ~7 years old?

Given that you're working with Dr Java, I presume this is classwork.  Hopefully, it is one not directly provided by the professor.

Comment: Nah, this is just my own code. So Dr Java works fine and recognized Java 6, but CodeRunner doesn't work! Dr Java also recognizes the Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you answered your own question. You are currently using 1.8, which is greater than the required 48 (see [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html)). To use version 48, you will have to install JDK 1.4. Also, make sure your system paths point to the 1.4 version after you've installed it.

Do a **which java** in your terminal and then go into that directory or run that executable with the **--version** switch to verify the version number. Sometimes, the installer will default to the newer version of Java while maintaining symbolic links to the older versions in the same folder. You will have to relink your Java to the older, 1.4 version if this is the case.

Comment: How do I change the required version though? I want to use Java 1.8 from now on.

Comment: If this is code you can modify yourself, you can update the source code to 1.8 compatibile and compile.

However, given you say you're using Dr Java which is a student/beginner focused IDE, I suspect the code in question is provided from classroom materials.  Seems like a discussion with the professor next class meeting is in order.

Comment: How do I update source code to 1.8 compatible and compile? I think the issue is that CodeRunner doesn't compile with the latest Java SDK. Is there something I need to change in the eval $compiler option?

Comment: MathBunny123 - @Jason is talking nonsense.  I your old code *should* compile with Java 8 without change (apart from a couple of edge cases, like if you used `enum` as an identifier).  The problem is the compiler that is being used ...

Comment: The issue is that CodeRunner appears to be asking for the older JDK for some odd reason. If it compiles/runs on Dr Java and not on CodeRunner, that is the issue then right?

Comment: A better question then: How can I use the Eclipse compiler from terminal? Like instead of javac. I'm setting up my own custom language so I'll just implement the compiler manually.